# Problems ordering sqlite by a column with special characters

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to sort table data on the basis of a column.The column contains String data like "Max" , "123" , "***" and some special characters like  . The query I have used to sort data alphabetically is following :

```
sqlDb.query(USER_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null,
         COLUMN_NAME_FIRST_NAME+ " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
```

The data I am getting after running this query is sorted properly with one exception.I am getting a row with column data  (special character) at the end in sorted table but I want this data row before alphabetic rows.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite will order based on the character ascii code.
There is a hack for your problem. Add space in the beginning for the data which starts with that special character. space is lower in order than the `a` character